# Categories associated to digraphs

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, graph-theory

Let's take a directed graph, or a digraph, $G=(V,E)$ given by a finite set of vertices $V$ and a finite set of edges $E$. We can assume that pairs of vertices can have parallel edges between them and we might have directed cycles. So equivalently I might say we have a quiver $G$.

To turn $G$ into a category we can take the *free* or *path* category $Free(G)$, where vertices $V$ become objects, and morphisms between vertices $x$ and $y$ are all the directed paths in $G$ from $x$ to $y$. The $Free$ construction is one direction in the adjointness between quivers and small categories. Now we can study the nerve of this category and its homotopy type, which turns out to be the same as that of the geometric realisation $|G|$ of $G$. Algebraically, in representation theory one also attaches to a quiver the path algebra which is essentially the same free construction as above, with product the composition of paths.

The $Free(G)$ is usually the category associated to a digraph I see around. My question is whether some other categories associated to digraphs have been studied, in topology, algebra, or any other relevant field? By have been studied I mainly mean constructions having reached research interest beyond one or two papers. But I'm generally interested in all examples. Also, if there is some good reason why $Free(G)$ is *the* categorical construction, I would like to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

In "Lawvere, Rosebrugh: Sets for Mathematics", a digraph G is associated with a functor $F : {\mathbf 2}^{op} \rightarrow {\mathbf {Set}}$, which maps a 3-element monoid $Hom(2,2)=\{id_2,c_0,c_1\}$ of endomorphisms of the 2-element set to the monoid of right actions of a digraph.

$F2 \cong G$

$(Fid_2)(e)=e$, for edge $e$

$(Fc_0)(e) = e_0$

$(Fc_1)(e) = e_1$

$(Fc_i)(v) = v$ for vertex $v$.

Here $c_0$ and $c_1$ are the obvious constant endomorphisms, $e_0$ is the start vertex associated with edge $e$, and $e_1$ is the end vertex.
Notice this approach confuses $V$ and $E$ sets, $F2 = F(1+1) \cong V+E = G$, and the subset containing only vertices or edges are defined by equations that arise from the right action.
By considering the contravariant functors as objects in a category and natural transformations as morphisms, the collection of digraphs is naturally isomorphic with the functor category $[{\mathbf 2}^{op}, {\mathbf {Set}}]$.

This is different than using a covariant functor from a category containing two-objects and two non-identity morphisms to the category ${\mathbf{ Set}}$, which models a digraph structurally as a pair of sets $V, E$.
See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver for definition. Here a coproduct is used instead, with idea that each member of a digraph is either a vertex or an edge. These two definitions modelling digraphs are sufficiently close to be confused with each other. To distinguish, it's important to separate left and right actions. Care must be used to distinguish correct order of composition. For right actions, the notation thus usually specifies a binary operation $(\cdot) : F2 \times Hom(2,2) \rightarrow F2$ called the action for applying the contravariant functor:
$e \cdot f {\stackrel{\text{def}}=}  (Ff)(e)$. Notice change in order of arguments. This ensures,
$(e \cdot f) \cdot g = e \cdot (f \circ g)$, the contravariant functor law on composition, which can be taken as definition of right action.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question?

Comment: I clarified that the category being described is a functor category corresponding to all digraphs.

Comment: The question asks for a mapping or functor $\mathbf{DiGraph} \to \mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: I suppose this approach would produce ${\mathbf {DiGraph}} \rightarrow [{\mathbf 2}^{op},{\mathbf {Set}}]$ by mapping $G \mapsto F$.

Comment: Yeah and therefore it's not an answer, right?

Comment: I suppose it would depend on how "categories associated to  digraphs" is interpreted. Functor categories are categories, but of course associating a category to a specific digraph is different than associating another category to all digraphs.

Comment: Just to let you know, the software has flagged this answer for having had many edits. It's best to limit them because otherwise the question keeps being bumped to the front page. If you foresee multiple rounds of corrections, try to save them up and do them all at once.